# JSF session timeout and primefaces push

Tags: jsf, session, primefaces, atmosphere

I have session timeout set in web.xml

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and track it down with my implementation of HttpSessionListener. I tested and see creation and destroying of each session - it work fine.

But, after adding **push services** in my app, etc:

xhtml:

```
<p:socket channel="/chat-notif">
    <p:ajax event="message" global="false"
        update="label-chat-new-msg  :f_chat_list :form-chat-conversation" />
</p:socket>
```

bean:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
eventBus.publish(PUSH_CHAT__MESSAGE, "new-msg");
```

resource:

```
@PushEndpoint(ChatController.PUSH_CHAT_MESSAGE)
public class ChatMessageResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
    public String onMessage(String finis) {
        return finis;
    }
}
```

**session has never timeout**, since push on periodic interval communicate with client page and update session idle timer, even when **user has no interaction on page**.

How should i avoid updating session lastAccessedTime on push messages?

PF 5.0, Mojarra 2.2.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason for updating session timers: On each push message, ajax is triggering backingbean method - that why session lastAccessedTime is updated.
Change to pure client side coding for push services:

```
    <p:socket onMessage="handleChatNotif" channel="/chat-notif" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleChatNotif(data) {
        $('.displayChatNotif').html(data);
        }
    </script>

<h:outputText styleClass="displayChatNotif" id="label-chat-new-msg" value="#{chatController.chatNotifications}" />
```

Now everything happens on client side and no request is send to web server, session timeout expired regulary.